# flutter upload file, with command is better putFile() vs putData()

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-storage

putFile() vs putData()

what is better, or what are the advantages and disadvantages of each command.

The Firebase documentation only says you should use putData() if putFile() is "not practical": https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files

What are these "not practical" cases ?

Answer (score 1):

The case for `putData` is when you have some raw data in memory that needs to be uploaded. Maybe you already read it from disk, or needed to load it from another source before uploading.  If this is not your case, then you can ignore it completely.